# Need help regarding html form submission in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my html form with MySQL database. So that what ever value the user inserts in the form our submitted to MySQL database . I have tried the following code but it is showing the following error on execution

'Undefined index: name in line 20' and 'Undefined index:address in line 21

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Address: <input type="text" name="address"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php code

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'database');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: please use mysqli version and you have not check when for is submitted or not..?

Comment: try, if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["address"])) {...}

Answer (score 0):

try this php code

```
  <?php

 define('DB_NAME', 'database');
 define('DB_USER', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');

 $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

 if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
  die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
 $name = '';
  $address = '';
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
  }
   if(isset($_POST['address'])){
   $address = $_POST['address'];
  }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  }
   mysql_close();
   ?>
```

Comment: But the input provided by the user is not displayed in database

Comment: what u mean is it not inserted..?

Comment: u can see this link and use mysqli or PDO version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813617/how-to-insert-a-record-in-mysql-with-php-with-an-html-form?rq=1

Comment: the code worked but still the values were not inserted in the database

Comment: i have used the pdo version

Comment: you have not check form submit or not  add name="save" your submit button then  try updated code

Comment: i am not using mysql database from xampp. I have downloaded the mysql workbench separately. So is that the problem.

Comment: the code worked. The problem was that the name and address column were set to null. I changed it to not null.